# Enable button after mandatory editetxt filled by user

Tags: android

I have one doubt. In my application I need to enable the submit button visibility once the user filled all mandatory edittexts fields.

Note : please don't suggest text watcher

Comment: i suggest that you show some code. no?

Comment: `Note: please don't suggest`... the correct answer?

Comment: Mr. frank : may I know why you said like this

Comment: guys i don't know why u are all down voted this question. may i know the reason please?

Comment: Because the correct answer would be based on watching the text changes on the EditTexts: You need something like: `(using the  TextWatcher) (for Each EditText) If the EditText text is not "" then increase an int. Else decrease it. Check if the int matches the number of required fields. If so, enable the button.` More or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO enable/disable UI elements on fly according with some validation rules is not that usability rule you *must* use without any exception ) Just do your checks when user clicks "Go".

Otherwise, you might do something like this:
1. You do need to setup some text edit event handler;
2. Upon text edit event you might engage timer for 0.3sec in which you check the text for validity and if yes then enable the button. When new  text edit event comes earlier then 0.3sec since the last one then you need to cancel all prev. timers that are still waiting.

One more way would be to do your checks in textedit "lost focus" event handler. But this is less understandable.

These all are too complex (many things to do) and more bugs risky for such an useless thing as UI enable/disable ) Just do your checks on "Go" button click and explain user what is wrong.

Comment: the OP has not giving any clue regarding what is going on in this code.

Comment: Yes, i think we answer, to spread and also gain knowledge, to questions that follow the guidelines. We do not answer just to gain reputations or just for the sake of answering.